# React.js: Make content of dropdown dynamic from API

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a library called react-select

The dropdown/select works fine. However, I want to make the content dynamic which would come from an API

The API response is like this:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "BIC": "AATCPHMMXXX",
    "BRSTN": "010140015",
    "NAME": "BANK CORPORATION"
        },
        {
    "id": 5,
    "BIC": "WEBPPHMMXXX",
    "BRSTN": "010350025",
    "NAME": "BANK OF THE WORLD"
        }
```

ClientMaintenancePage.js

```
    import Select from 'react-select';
    ...

    const optionsBrstn = [
        { label: "BIC1 BRSTN1 NAME1", value: BRSTN1 },
        { label: "BIC2 BRSTN2 NAME2", value: BRSTN2 },
        { label: "BIC3 BRSTN3 NAME3", value: BRSTN3 }
    ...
      ];

    <Select options={ optionsBrstn } />
```

I want it to appear in the dropdown with that pattern. Any suggestion would help, thanks.

ANSWER:

```
    import Select from 'react-select';
    ...

    const retrieveBanks = useCallback(() => {
        ClientMaintenanceService.retrieveBanks()
        .then((response) => {
          setDataBanks(response.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("ClientMaintenancePage - retrieveBanks catch >>> " + err)
        })
      });

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveBanks();
      }, []);

    const newOptions = dataBanks.map(({BIC, BRSTN, NAME}) => ({
        label: BIC + "  " + BRSTN + "  " + NAME ,
        value: BRSTN
      }))

    return (
    <Select 
                  isSearchable="true"
                  options={ newOptions } 
                  placeholder="Select BIC / BRSTN / Bank Name..." 
                />
    )
```

Comment: so you want to convert api response to options format?

Comment: Yes, I would like the json response to be rendered in options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format your data response and update options select in `useEffect`, check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-rgb-6lnhc)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const [optionsBrstn, setOption] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataResponse = [
      {
        id: 1,
        BIC: "AATCPHMMXXX",
        BRSTN: "010140015",
        NAME: "BANK CORPORATION"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        BIC: "AATCPHMMXXX",
        BRSTN: "010140015",
        NAME: "BANK CORPORATION"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        BIC: "WEBPPHMMXXX",
        BRSTN: "010350025",
        NAME: "BANK OF THE WORLD"
      }
    ];
    const newOption = dataResponse.map(item => {
      return {
        label: `${item.BIC} ${item.BRSTN} ${item.NAME}`,
        value: item.BRSTN
      };
    });
    setOption(newOption);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={optionsBrstn} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

PS: Currently CodeSandBox have some errors, you need to close this aleart (click on X at top right corner)
[image]

Comment: Hi, may I ask why this part is making an error, const newOption = dataResponse.map(item => {
      return {
        label: `${item.BIC} ${item.BRSTN} ${item.NAME}`,
        value: item.BRSTN
      };
    });
    setOption(newOption);
  }, []);

Comment: This now works perfectly fine, just missed a semicolon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @iamhuynq, may I also ask how can I pass the value of the dropdown once set, to a method then to an axios post request. Also, I edited my question to include your answer. Thanks

Comment: Also, I think I'm missing something. How do I add state to the dropdown using hooks? TIA

Comment: please wait, i will check

Comment: Hi, i updated [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-rgb-6lnhc) , can you check? Now you can get selected option from`selectedOption.value` state

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to update the array of objects structure, try this.

```js
optionsBrstn = response.map(({BIC, BRSTN, NAME}) => ({
    label: BIC + " " + BRSTN + " " + NAME,
    value: BRSTN
}))
```

so `optionsBrstn` will be:

```js
[
  {label: "AATCPHMMXXX 010140015 BANK CORPORATION", value: "010140015"},
  {label: "WEBPPHMMXXX 010350025 BANK OF THE WORLD", value: "010350025"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using hooks you can call the api in a `useEffect` with no dependencies and store the result of your api at the state of your function component and use the state value to show dropdown, basically you need a `useEffect` for api call and a `useState` to store the api data in it.

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {

  const [dropdownData, setDropdownData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetch(url, config)
       .then(result => result.json())
       .then(data => {
         setDropdownData(data)
       })
   

  }, [])

  
  return (
    
    <Select options={ dropdownData } />

  )
 
}
```

#### NOTE:

please note that fetch inside `useEffect` is just for demonstration purposes, you might have a separate function for handeling api calls or maybe if you are using redux, that might be the related action call; in redux way, also note that you might get the value from your store with `useSelector`, and that is basically another topic that requires you to read the redux hook api!

Comment: Tried this but it did not show properly on the Select.